# how to use condition in this button to show alertdialog in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. productDetails

```
child: ButtonTheme(
                                    child: (TextButton(
                                      child: Text(
                                        'Demande de prix',
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ),
                                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: Colors.white,
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2664B5),
                                        onSurface: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => DemandeDevis(
                                              productName:
                                                  (selectedProduitslist[index]
                                                          .titre)
                                                      .toUpperCase(),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    )),
                                  ),
```

2.demandedevis

```
AlertDialog(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  elevation: 20,
  content: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: ListBody(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Text(
              "Demande de prix",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue[900],
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: ResponsiveFlutter.of(context).wp(50),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: largeurController,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              // validator: (text) {
              //   if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
              //     return "Champ obligatoire";
              //   }
              //   return null;
              // },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                hintText: 'Largeur (m)',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue[900],
                  fontSize: 10,
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide:
                      BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[900], width: 0.5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                ),
                contentPadding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 0),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: ResponsiveFlutter.of(context).wp(50),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: longeurController,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              // validator: (text) {
              //   if (text == null || text.isEmpty) {
              //     return "Champ obligatoire";
              //   }
              //   return null;
              // },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                hintText: 'Longeur (m)',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue[900],
                  fontSize: 10,
                ),
```

Comment: Which button? can you specify?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are asking how to show a dialog when a button is pressed.

Every button has an `onPressed :` argument, in that onPressed function you can execute the `showDialog()` function to show a dialog in the UI. Given below is the code snippet.

```
TextButton(
 child: Text(
             'Yes!',
              style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),),
              onPressed: () => 
               {

                //This is the function that will execute when the button is pressed

                showDialog(
                     context : context,
                     builder : (context) => AlertDialog()
                          );                
               },
            ),
         );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have other issues I need to use condition because I have some category, so when x category is selected it is necessary that the Alert Dialog showing a specific input...

Comment: If you explain clearly maybe I could be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would like to do some onPressed functionality based on condition, like if(condition) do that, else do that...

1. You could do this by inline condition, also called ternary operator.
   For example:

   ```
   onPressed: (condition != null) ? () => Navigator.push() : () => showAlertDialog()
   ```

   You read this like:

   ```
   (your condition) ? [if true ->] do that : [else ->] do that.
   ```

   You could also nest this expression.
2. As an alternative you could add a function, which calls other conditioned functions.

   ```
   ...
   onPressed: _decisionFunction,
   ...

   void _decisionFunction(){
      if(condition == true){
         Navigator.push(...);
      } else {
         showDialog(...);
      }
   }
   ```